Looking for an Iwo Jima WW2 documentary made between 2000-2007ish
I'm looking for a documentary about Iwo Jima. I've seen it back between 2002-2005ish ,it was all color, a newer documentary. I haven't been able to find this documentary and I looked at least once a week for an hour.
It was narrated and didn't use interviews from survivors etc. It used passages from soldiers' diaries etc. to tell the story, it didn't just stop at the Mt. Suribachi flag raising. I know it wasn't 36 days of hell, red blood black sand, heroes of iwo jima, the boys of h company (although if I had to compare it to one it would be this other then it was real footage in color, not actors).
I remember distinctly one passage, the guy talked about his friend using a bayonette to get gold teeth from dead Japanese soldiers and how he was sickened by it etc. Then there was a part they got stuck in the foothills and the tank they were hiding behind. Every time someone went to use the phone thing to tell the tank commander where to aim they'd get shot.

@panther Thanks for the edit.
